# What versions of gRPC modules and tools are compatible for v 1.8.0?

Tags: c#, grpc

I'm trying to compile a simple project with the latest gRPC dlls and tools. But I'm running into compatibility issues with the Grpc.Tools runtime and the Grpc.Core.

How do I know which versions of Grpc.Core, Grpc.Tools, and Google.Protocol Buffers are compatible with each other.

Answer (score 0):

After some trials with different configurations, I found these to work:

- Google.Protobuf 3.5.0
- Grpc 1.8.0
- Grpc.Core 1.8.0
- Grpc.Tools 1.8.0
- System.Interactive.Async.3.1.1

and

- Google.Protobuf 3.2.0
- Grpc 1.7.3
- Grpc.Core 1.7.3
- Grpc.Tools 1.7.3
- System.Interactive.Async.3.1.1

and

- Google.Protobuf 3.2.0
- Grpc 1.2.2
- Grpc.Core 1.2.2
- Grpc.Tools 1.2.2
- System.Interactive.Async.3.1.1

I was mistakenly adding these as regular depenedencies instead of letting NuGet manage it all. All I needed to was add the "Grpc" which would auto-add Core and the System dlls, and also make sure the right runtime dlls (e.g. grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll) got in place.

The other issue I was having is you MUST have System.Interactive.Async.3.1.1 as the one that is loaded and not the default version for .NET 4.5. Otherwise, I was seeing the rpc calls hang with no errors. Visual Studio was not coping the 3.1.1 dll into the bin because it assumed what was in GAC was close enough. To solve that I had to add the Grpc nuget package to all my dlls and exes and not trust the transitive assembly copying.